# How to profile PostgreSQL Database?

Tags: postgresql, profiling, monitoring

I want to profile (keep an Eye on) all the activities that goes on in a Database which is in PostgreSQL.

Is there any such utility which will help me do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For "keeping an eye", I use [pgtop](http://ptop.projects.postgresql.org/), a program which deliberately mimics Unix 'top' command.

Comment: To save someone a minute or two: I found this only under the package name ptop in Debian, though the command itself is called pg_top.

Comment: link is not available anymore?

Comment: @GunnlaugurBriem Since version 4 it has been renamed to pgtop.

Answer (score 36):

"Keep an eye on" and "profile" are two quite different tasks in my view.

For profiling (not a live view on what's going on right now, but to see which queries take most time etc), check out pgFouine:

http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/

This will let you see which queries are resource intensive, and take appropriate action: Add missing indexes, rewrite queries using other techiques etc.

Comment: Link is dead. Read @l-g answer: pgbadger as substitute.

Answer (score 12):

[PgBadger](https://pgbadger.darold.net) is an actively maintained profiling tool that provides very detailed reports and graphs ([see examples](https://pgbadger.darold.net/#reports)). It can process large volumes of PostgreSQL logs to [answer questions](https://pgbadger.darold.net/documentation.html#FEATURE) like:

- The most frequent waiting queries.
- Queries that waited the most.
- The slowest queries.

(PgBadger was explicitly built to "replace and outperform" pgFouine, which has not been maintained since about 2010.)

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you're looking at what's going on, regarding selects, updates, deletes, and so on, there are a few views in the `pg_catalog` schema, I mainly use `pg_stat_user_tables` and `pg_stat_user_indexes` but there are many more, all within `pg_stat*`.

There also is the `pg_stat_activity` view which tells you what's running on your server right now.

I've hacked together four munin plugins that uses the user_tables and user_indexes, they're available [there](http://mat.cc/distfiles/munin/)

Comment: mat, do you still have the plugins available somewhere? The link points to 404 not found

Comment: Hum, unless I'm mistaken, munin comes with a dozen plugins for postgresql that do exactly what mine did. If I'm mistaken, tell me, I'll try to find out what happened with the ones I crafted.

Comment: Munin project [here](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/WikiStart#download)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Nagios-Plugin script](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/nagiosplugins/) or [check_postgres.pl](http://bucardo.org/nagios/)