# Django/Pyramid debugtoolbar: is it possible to see not only making query time, but also query duration in database?

Tags: django, sqlalchemy, pyramid, werkzeug, django-debug-toolbar

And if not, how to check? I'm using SQLAlchemy.

Thanks!

Comment: you're using the pyramid or django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both projects use werkzeug as far as I can say. Pyramid does use it, and I only heard about django using it but never tried. That said both toolbars should be very different  because they depends on different projects.

If you want the query time for sqlalchemy. There are a couple of ways to do that as it's been discussed there.

[How can I profile a SQLAlchemy powered application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171166/how-can-i-profile-a-sqlalchemy-powered-application)

With plain old python logging you can guess the time between querys if you enable debugging. The pyramid toolbars allows profiling so you can also there check how much time it took for which functions.

According to the docs, the debug toolbar in sqlalchemy displays time in ms for queries.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_debugtoolbar/en/latest/api.html

Comment: Can you clarify the 1st 2 sentences. It looks to me like you say both tolbards depend on werzeug?

Comment: Speaking for Pyramid: The code was copied from werkzeug, but adapted to fit Pyramid. I read this somewhere, and I know this cuz werkzeug does not yet support Python 3, while Pyramid toolbar does.