# How to set the foreign key to a default value on delete?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to auto set the product `category_id` to a default value when category is deleted? For example `1` to point to the first category.

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    content = db.Column(db.Text(), unique=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    atime = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    def __init__(self, name, content, category_id):
        self.name = name
        self.content = content
        self.category_id = category_id
        self.atime = datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product %r>' % self.id

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref='category', cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) > 0:
            self.name = kwargs['name']

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % self.name
```

I don't want to use cascade to delete them!

Answer (score 37):

There are two things that need to be performed in orchestration here:

1. Define the Foreign Key with proper referential action
2. Configure the cascade option of the SA relationship

I think the cleanest way would be to set the `category_id` to a `NULL` value when its Category is deleted: `SET NULL` is one of the possible [Referential Actions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Referential_Actions) of the `ON DELETE` clause, which you can add to your [ForeignKey](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html?highlight=foreignkey#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey) definition:

```
category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id', ondelete='SET NULL'))
```

In the same way you can use an option [`SET DEFAULT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#SET_DEFAULT), but in this case you need to also configure the default value for the column `category_id`: `category_id = Column(..., server_default=1)`. Note that implementations of these differ between different RDBMS.

As to the `cascade` option: You should basically remove the `cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan"` from your `products` relationship definition. In fact, you want to ensure that `delete, delete-orphan` are not there.

Having said that, you really need to test your code to cover different scenarios, as two different deletions of the `Category` object might produce different results depending on your RDBMS and SA configuration:

```
# scenario-1: delete in session: SA might set category_id of all chilren Products to None
c1 = session.query(Category).get(1)
session.delete(c1)
session.commit()

# scenario-2: delete without loading an object into the session: SA will perform no additional logic
session.query(Category).filter(Category.id == 2).delete()
session.commit()
```

Hope all this points you in the right direction. As usual, enabled SQL logging in your test code using [`echo=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171166/how-can-i-profile-a-sqlalchemy-powered-application/1175677#1175677) or just by configuring `logging` module, and you will see what SA is doing to your database. Other changes which which you did not see in the SQL were done by RDBMS itself given your Referential Action.