# Reading large files using SQLalchemy

Tags: csv, sqlalchemy, python-2.7

I am trying to read a 200 MB csv file using SQLalchemy. Each line has about 30 columns, of which, I use only 8 columns using the code below. However, the code runs really slow! Is there a way to improve this? I would like to use map/list comprehension or other techniques. As you an tell, I am a newbie. Thanks for your help.

```
for ddata in dread:        
    record = DailyData()
    record.set_campaign_params(pdata) #Pdata is assigned in the previous step         
    record.set_daily_data(ddata) #data is sent to a class method where only 8 of 30 items in the list are used       
    session.add(record)
    session.commit() #writing to the SQL database.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't commit on every record.  commit or just flush every 1000 or so:

```
for i, data in enumerate(csv_stuff):
    rec = MyORMObject()
    rec.set_stuff(data)
    session.add(rec)
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        session.flush()
session.commit() # flushes everything remaining + commits
```

if that's still giving you problems then do some basic profiling, see my post at [How can I profile a SQLAlchemy powered application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171166/how-can-i-profile-a-sqlalchemy-powered-application/1175677#1175677)

Comment: Thank you! This resulted in a big boost in speed. I will also use profiler to educate myself more on SQLalchemy optimization