# Python coroutines on builtin functions

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine, python-asyncio, built-in

I'm currently using python 3.4, @coroutine decorator and yield keyword (in tornado) for asynchronous purposes.
I wrote an ORM with a lot of objects instrospection which call a "slow" database and override built-in functions like `__init__` or `__contains__`.
My question is :
For example, when my asynchronous code is in the `__contains__` definition of an object, how can I call it implicitly/transparently when I use the "in" operator in my tornado controller?
Implicit because I don't want the controller-side developper to change his code when he call built-in functions.

Comment: Can you show us some code sample that demonstrates what you're asking? This question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, the answer is that you can't; there's no way to write a magic method as an explicit coroutine and have it behave properly when called implicitly by Python. This is a [well-known](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/pep_ideas/async_programming.html#gevent-and-pep-3156) [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503103/2073595) of explicit coroutines.

So, if you have this:

```
class SomeObj:
    @coroutine
    def __contains__(self, obj):
        exists = yield self.somemethod(obj)
        return exists
```

This won't do what you want it to do:

```
o = SomeObj()
'x' in o # This won't work right
```

Python doesn't expect `__contains__` to be a coroutine, and won't behave properly if it is - the core of the language doesn't know anything about `tornado`, or `asyncio`, or any other frameworks used to implement these coroutines, and won't integrate with them properly. The same applies for other implicitly-called magic methods like `__init__`, `__getattr__`, etc.

If you need to suspend, you have to explicitly call a method using `yield` or `yield from` (depending on the framework). Generally, this means using a function (or perhaps a `@classmethod`) to instantiate your `SomeObj` and then having that function call a method that does the slow, asynchronous call, rather than doing it all in `__init__`:

```
@coroutine
def create_someobj():
   s = SomeObj()
   yield s.slow_init()
   return s
```

And just calling a normal coroutine method called something like `contains` instead of relying on the `in` keyword. Not ideal, but that's the world we live in.

That said, there is some effort being made to improve this; [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/), in addition to introducing a new syntax for coroutines, adds support for asynchronous for-loops and context managers (using new magic methods specifically designed to be asynchronous). So starting with Python 3.5, you can this:

```
async def some_func():  # async is used instead of a coroutine decorator
    # Assume SomeObj implements __anext__, __aiter__, __aenter__, and __aexit__
    s = SomeObj()
    async for item in s:  # You can suspend while iterating over s using __anext__
       print(item)

    async with SomeObj() as s: # You can suspend on enter and exit of this context manager using __aenter__ and __aexit__
        await s.some_method() # await is used instead of yield from
```