# Saving API output async using SQLAlchemy and Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, tornado

I want to save the output of a currency API in a MySQL table using SQLAlchemy and Tornado but when I loop over the JSON results the API returned and I insert each one to the database, the app get stuck. No other procedures can be executed until all inserts are completed when this happens.

I guess I should execute the insert also as a coroutine but not sure how to do that. I know there are several libraries for async SQLAlchemy such as [Asyncio](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiopg) but are they really needed when using Tornado?

The code below blocks when executing the loop on the bottom and Currency_rate

```
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
import urllib

import tornado.web
import tornado.httpclient
from tornado import gen

from src.entities.currency import list_currencies, view_iso_a3_currency
from src.entities.currency_rate import Currency_rate

@gen.coroutine
def currencylayer_currency_rate():
    http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    base_url = "http://apilayer.net/api/live?"
    base_currency = view_iso_a3_currency('USD')
    vars = {'access_key': 'APIKEY', 'source': base_currency.iso_a3, 'format': 1}
    url = base_url + urllib.parse.urlencode(vars)
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    if response.error:
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
    json = tornado.escape.json_decode(response.body)

    timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(json['timestamp'])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    json_rates = json['quotes']
    for key, value in json_rates.items():
        quote_currency = view_iso_a3_currency(str(key)[-3:])
        if not quote_currency:
            continue
        currency_rate = Currency_rate(m_currency_id1 = base_currency.id,
                                      m_currency_id2 = quote_currency.id,
                                      rate = Decimal(value),
                                      date = timestamp,
                                      create_user = 1,
                                      update_user = 1,
                                      active = 1)
        currency_rate.add()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately SQLAlchemy is not async, every request (operation) to db will block. Even more, concept of ORM is hard to make it work asynchronously (ref: [How to make SQLAlchemy in Tornado to be async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491564/how-to-make-sqlalchemy-in-tornado-to-be-async)).

You maybe interested in projects (async):

- [momoko](http://momoko.61924.nl/en/latest/) - postgres Tornado-based client, it is not an ORM,
- [aiopg](http://aiopg.readthedocs.org/en/stable/index.html) - postgres [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio.html)-based client (Tornado 4.3 and above), support for sqlalchemy query builders
- [tornado-mysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/Tornado-MySQL) - MySQL Tornado-based client

Hint:

```
response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
if response.error:
    raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
```

The yield will also raise a HTTPError on error, hence explicit raise is needless.

Comment: Thank you kAlmAcetA! Asyncio looks great as I'll be able to use SQLAlchemy. Thanks for the hint by the way :)