# What driver for SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL with gevent?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, gevent

Based on [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16503103/518169) by zzzeek, I would like to use SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL with gevent. My problem is that I don't know what is an up-to-date PostgreSQL driver for such scenario.

Before I always used psycopg2, as I found it to be extremely stable and reliable.

My problem is that if I understand right psycopg2 needs to be monkey-patched to work under gevent, right? And the only way to do it is to use [psycogreen](https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/), a project whose latest PyPi release is from 2012, has not been updated since 2015 and doesn't support Python 3.

How do you use SQLAlchemy in a concurrent way today? Is it simply not possible?

Comment: `psycogreen` works fine in Python 3. You can also just copy the [code](https://bitbucket.org/dvarrazzo/psycogreen/src/115d0627da1ac9ff48c0cb9287257cd35868cdf9/psycogreen/gevent.py) directly if you want -- there's nothing Python 2-specific in there.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my own psycopg2 gevent code.  This sets up a pool so you can manage connections, uses gevent threading, and handles low latency connections well.

[Python Postgres psycopg2 ThreadedConnectionPool exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532301/python-postgres-psycopg2-threadedconnectionpool-exhausted/49366850#49366850)