# SQLAlchemy: How do I acquire query response time statistics?

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlalchemy

Using plain MySQL shell, it provides me the information on how long the query took. E.g.

> 41 rows in set (0.023 sec)

Now using Python/SQLAlchemy in plain SQL, how do I get that information?

```
db.engine.execute("SELECT id FROM [...]")
```

I seem unable to find any functionality in the SQLAlchemy API for it. I could of course comparing timestamps before and after the statement, but that's what MySQL is already doing for me I guess.

Comment: I think that this answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8428546/1527018

Comment: @mic4ael Well, it provides some convenience, but it still reinventes the wheel on timetracking I see.